# TrySetWallpaperImageAsync() always returns false

Tags: c#, windows-10, uwp

I'm trying to set the wallpaper to an image on my Windows 10 device:

```
var fileName = postInf.title + ".jpg";
BitmapImage img = new BitmapImage();

bool success = false;
if (UserProfilePersonalizationSettings.IsSupported())
{
    // read from pictures library
    var pictureFile = await KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary.GetFileAsync(fileName);
    using (var pictureStream = await pictureFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read))
    {
        img.SetSource(pictureStream);
    }

    UserProfilePersonalizationSettings profileSettings = UserProfilePersonalizationSettings.Current;
    success = await profileSettings.TrySetWallpaperImageAsync(pictureFile);
} 
return success;
```

The storagefile is created fine, have tried with various images from various folders (e.g. My Pictures, Assets, LocalState); always returns false and wallpaper is not set? I have read/write permissions to pictures library, have tried running in debug and release versions. Apparently others are also having this [problem](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2a717355-7915-4ca8-bf8c-0389c254520f/uwpccx-how-to-use-trysetwallpaperimageasync?forum=wpdevelop).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your app can't set wallpapers from any folder. Copy file in ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder and set wallpaper from there.
My code:

```
    if (list.SelectedIndex != -1)
    {
      var data = list.SelectedItem as ThumbItem;
      StorageFile newFile = await data.File.CopyAsync(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder);
      await SetWallpaperAsync(newFile);
    }

async Task<bool> SetWallpaperAsync(StorageFile fileItem)
        {
            bool success = false;
            if (UserProfilePersonalizationSettings.IsSupported())
            {
                UserProfilePersonalizationSettings profileSettings = UserProfilePersonalizationSettings.Current;
                success = await profileSettings.TrySetWallpaperImageAsync(fileItem);
            }
            return success;
        }
```

Comment: Right on, I didn't realize you had to actually save the file to your local folder before you could set it as the wallpaper. Thanks!