# TrySetWallpaperImageAsync always returns false even though I'm using Application LocalFolder

Tags: c#, uwp

The TryWallpaperImageAsync method always returns false and does not set the wallpaper. If you look at this question: [TrySetWallpaperImageAsync() always returns false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33338571/trysetwallpaperimageasync-always-returns-false), you will see their fix was relocating the image to the application's localfolder. I am doing that here, but for some reason my wallpaper is still not being changed. What could cause this method to fail?

```
string name = "wallpaper.jpg";
var file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync($"{ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path}\\{name}");
var success = await SetWallpaperAsync(file);

async Task<bool> SetWallpaperAsync(StorageFile fileItem)
{
    bool success = false;
    if (UserProfilePersonalizationSettings.IsSupported())
    {
        UserProfilePersonalizationSettings profileSettings = UserProfilePersonalizationSettings.Current;
        success = await profileSettings.TrySetLockScreenImageAsync(fileItem);
    }
    return success;
}
```

Comment: Does this apply (from [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.System.UserProfile.UserProfilePersonalizationSettings))? - "When you set an image more than once, the new image file must have a different name than the previously set image. If you set a new image using a file with the same name as the previous image, it will fail."

Comment: Yes!! changing the name to $"{Guid.NewGuid()}.jpg" actually worked! I guess I need to read the documentation more closely next time. Go ahead and answer the question with this so I can give you credit please @PeterTorr-MSFT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [documented limitation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.System.UserProfile.UserProfilePersonalizationSettings) with the API when dealing with duplicate filenames.

If the file you are trying to set as the wallpaper has the same name as the current wallpaper, the system will ignore the request and no-op the operation (returning `false`).

You should always use a unique filename when setting the wallpaper to ensure it gets set correctly.